# Why does audio streaming interfere with iBeacon Ranging and events on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, ibeacon, ios-bluetooth

I'm working on an iOS iBeacon app that uses CoreLocation APIs for both ranging and monitoring regions for beacons. I've noticed that if I turn on audio streaming by pairing my phone to my car and making a phone call that's broadcast over the car speakers or running an audio streaming app like Pandora through the car speakers then ranging stops and I receive didExitRegion callbacks. If I start/stop audio streaming by pressing the power button on my car's dashboard ranging stops/starts in concert and around 30 seconds after starting audio the app gets the didExitRegion callback.

This is with the beacon and the phone within a couple feet of each other and not moving. It happens both with the app in the foreground and background.

I guess there's some kind of priority issue going on with the phone's broadcast of audio over BT taking priority of its listening for iBeacons but it seems extreme.

My beacons are custom with a broadcast interval of 2 secs and power of 4dB.

I'm on the latest iOS 17.x on a recent iPhone and other users have reported the same issue.

Is this a well-known issue?

Is there some way to mitigate this?